# Aggregate Data/ Create a New Variable in SPSS

Tags: aggregate, spss

I have looked at the aggregate data questions on this forum and elsewhere - but I don't quite see an answer that helps me but that may be non-understanding on my behalf.I apologize.  I have a huge amount of raw data test findings and I want to aggregate certain scores into one mean score.  I can do this by creating a new variable in **compute > transform**  but I cannot do this for 330+ by adding it 1 + 2 + 3 all by hand.  My question is: How can I aggregate hundreds of scores and calculate a new mean score as a new variable in a quick and intelligent fashion that so far eludes me? For example, I have 339 latency measures for 50 participants.  I want to calculate ONE overall latency score as a new variable. Thanks! I am desperate for direction.

Answer (score 0):

If your variables are contiguous in the file you can use the `SUM` command using `TO` to specify the variables in simple syntax.

```
COMPUTE SumX = SUM(X1 to X330).
```