# SPSS: creating new continuous variable from a series of dichotomous variables

Tags: spss

I have a series of dichotomous variables drawn from the following question:

> Have any of the following substances caused you concerns over the last 3 months:
>
> - Opioid {0 = "No"; 1 = "Yes"}
> - Cannabis {0 = "No"; 1 = "Yes"}
> - Alcohol {0 = "No"; 1 = "Yes"}
> - Amphetamine-type stimulant {0 = "No"; 1 = "Yes"}

I would like to compute a new numeric variable that tallies the number of times the individual has responded 'yes'; e.g. if they have two drugs of concern the new variable will count '2'.

Comment: The "number of times" something happens is discrete, not continuous. After all, it can only take the values 1, 2, 3, ... $\quad $ and that's *not* continuous.

Comment: Hint:  Go to Transform...Compute and follow your nose.  Or look up the "sum" function.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by `COMPUTE` procedure using the `SUM` function. See the documentation for more details. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20682876/577857).